# S3 putobject throwing Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm working on uploading local files to aws s3 in C# .net, and I'm using `putObjectRequest` to make the request to aws s3, however, I've just received a thrown exception:  `Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.`. Here is what I'm doing:

```
try {
    string testString = @"C:\Path\to\object files\file.jpg";
    PutObjectRequest objReq = new PutObjectRequest
    {
        Key = key,
        ContentType = "JPG",
        BucketName = bucket + "/" + FolderName,
        CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicReadWrite,
        FilePath = testString
    };
    PutObjectResponse response = s3Client.PutObject(objReq);
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

I carefully checked the `BucketName`, `RegionEndPoint` and `ServiceURL`, they have been set correctly, so I'm thinking the `FilePath` is not correct. However, after searching the file path format in C#, I think I'm using the correct operator to escape the backslash. Is there any other cause can lead to this exception?

The entire stackTrace is like this:

> at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind
>   uriKind)
>
> at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
>
> at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointResolver.DetermineEndpoint(IClientConfig
>   config, IRequest request)
>
> at
>   Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3PostMarshallHandler.ProcessRequestHandlers(IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)
>
> at
>   Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3PostMarshallHandler.PreInvoke(IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)
>
> at
>   Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3PostMarshallHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)
>
> at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)
>
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Marshaller.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)
>
> at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)
>
> at
>   Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3PreMarshallHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)
>
> at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)
>
> at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)
>
> at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)
>
> at
>   Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ExceptionHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)
>
> at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)
>
> at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)
>
> at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)
>
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)
>
> at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RuntimePipeline.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)
>
> at
>   Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.Invoke[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest
>   request, IMarshaller`2 marshaller, ResponseUnmarshaller unmarshaller)
>
> at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.PutObject(PutObjectRequest request)
>
> at Camera_Capture.UploadFileToAmazonS3(String Filepath, String
>   camstring, String SerialNumber) in C:\path\to\Program.cs:line 371

Comment: It's possible that `FilePath` is expected to start with "file://".

Comment: Can you post the entire exception, including stack trace?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I've added the error StackTrace

Comment: @jingx If I'm giving the absolute path from my local drive, I think `file://` is not necessary.

Comment: `Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointResolver.DetermineEndpoint` would appear to indicate something is wrong with your endpoint config. Are you *absolutely* double-triple sure the ServiceUrl and RegionEndpoint are correct?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes I am, the ServiceUrl is standard: `s3.amazonaws.com` and the only region I'm using is `RegionEndpoint.USWest2`

Comment: @Blorgbeard `AmazonS3Config()` is not constructing config with given RegionEndpoint I mentioned. This is why I got this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out to be a very misleading error message. The problem is from `AmazonS3Client(accesskey, secretkey, AmazonS3Config config);` was not getting the `RegionEndpoint` when `AmazonS3Config` was constructed. I changed the S3 client constructor to `AmazonS3Client(accesskey, secretkey, RegionEndpoint.USWest2);` and it resolved the error for me. I think Amazon itself should return a message of `RegionEndpoint of config is null` rather than this misleading message `Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined`
 that .net will throw, because it can be caused by many other reasons.